# How to calculate customer retention dollar rate (C$R)?

Tags: excel, statistics, formula, tableau-api

I want to calculate customer dollar retention rate C$R (end_value/start_value for a certain period of time).

For example, if I want to to calculate C$R for each month, should I use:

```
avg(end_value/start_value)
```

or

`avg(end_value)/avg(start_value)` ?

[image]

which makes more sense?

Comment: You do realize they have two different outcomes?

Comment: I think this question should be at https://stats.stackexchange.com/